# Ошибка 500 Internal Server Error при использовании ajax в Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Использование в Wordpress следующего кода возвращает ошибку 500 Internal Server Error. В чём может быть причина?

```
add_action('wp_ajax_hello', 'say_hello');

function say_hello() {

    echo 'Привет пользователь!'
}
```

Comment: Нет точки с запятой после echo. И нет die(). Это то, что на поверхности.

Comment: Поставил точку с запятой после echo и функцию wp_die();. Теперь другая проблема. Функция возвращает ноль. В консоли: 400 Bad Request

Comment: Мы так можем бесконечно отладкой заниматься. Создавайте новый вопрос, выкладывайте туда код целиком, js и php. А перед этим прочитайте kama про ajax в wp

Comment: Всё проблема решена. Спасибо.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.